# How to attach client certificate to AspNetCore TestServer api?

Tags: asp.net-core, .net-core, asp.net-core-2.0

I'm looking at `Microsoft.AspNetCore.TestHost.TestServer` in the Microsoft source code.  There I see the `CreateClient()` property that is `HttpClient` objects.

So how do I attached the client certificate for Digitial Signature in xUnit Test?

`HttpClient` example would be this.

```
var x509Certificate2 = new X509Certificate();  // Pretend it contains certificate data already.

var httpClientHandler = new HttpClientHandler() {
    ClientCertificateOptions = ClientCertificateOption.Manual
};
httpClientHandler.ClientCertificates.Add(x509Certificate2);

using (var httpClient = new HttpClient(httpClientHandler))
{
}
```

Now using the `TestServer`

```
var testServer = new TestServer();

testServer.CreateClient();  // How do I attached client certificate here?
```

So, how do we attach the client certificate here?  For `CreateClient()`

Also, I can try to make do with implementing the `HttpRequestMessage` but it doesn't support that certificate option either.

Comment: Need help with this too :)

Answer (score 0):

You may try to use the testServer.SendAsync(...) method and just construct your HttpContext from there.

```
var result = await server.SendAsync(context =>
                                    {
                                        context.Connection.ClientCertificate = myClientCertificate;
                                        context.Request.Method = "POST";
                                     });
```

Just make sure to specify the Path and the Body as needed.